# timeout with kakfkaAppender in log4j?

Tags: apache-kafka, timeout, log4j

When I use the `KafkaAppender` of log4j I have a problem when I put a single broker, but it is stopped. The problem is the `KafkaAppender` waits for a very long time before failing. I use `syncsend=false` I want to set some timeout so the appender wouldn't wait for such a long time.

Could you tell me how I need to configure the `KafkaAppender` in order to prevent this wait?

Comment: Some more detail is needed in order to resolve your issue. It's not clear what is the problem. Is it the KafkaAppender waiting for the broker to become active? Maybe you'd like to prevent waiting or set the timeout so the wait wouldn't be so long?

Comment: Dear sir, I put un the config a kafka bromea that is down. Bueno the ip exist and the broker si config bug stopped. The problema si that the appender needle a lot of timeout time to known this sitiation and queue the menssages. I need config appender to Walt few time when the broker si down

Comment: I need know how I need config the timeout to preventa watling  long time when the broker si down or respond slowly.

Comment: Dear sir, I put the config a kafka broker that is down. The ip exist and the broker if config but it stopped. The problema if that the appender needle a lot of timeout time to known this sitiation and queue the menssages. I need config appender to ealt few time when the broker si down

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not quite sure what your problem is.
It seems that you want to set some timeout, what is unclear what precise behaviour would you expect. It would be nice if you would share your appender configuration. If that's fine for you then you can find me on Linkedin and there ask me the question in the native language. Then I would edit the question to better reflect your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeout setting on `KafkaAppender` itself, but there are a few timeout options that can be configured on `KafkaProducer`. The options are described in the Kafka [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs).

Here you have example kafka appender configuration with two kafka producer timeout settings with their default values:

```xml
 <Appenders>
    <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="log-test">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%date %message"/>
      <Property name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:9092</Property>
      <Property name="request.timeout.ms">30000</Property><!-- 30 seconds -->
      <Property name="transaction.timeout.ms">60000</Property><!-- 1 minute -->
    </Kafka>
  </Appenders>
```

You might want to play with those to get the expected behaviour.

Also, remember that the `syncSend` option was added in log4j 2.8 version. If you use older version it will have no effect.

Comment: Dear sir I need know the diferente timeout using in kafja appender. I need know the timeout uses un connect to broker. I try to dissmis the time that waut when the kafka broker si down

Comment: There is no documented configuration property for connection timeout. If changing ones suggested by me does not help, there is nothing that can be done.

Comment: I try to test the properties that you suggest.

Comment: @barbyware Please let us know about the results